# Javascript: How to add hyperlinks to changing images

Tags: javascript, html

hey all my first post on this forum so please excuse me.

so i have this code that changes images every 2 seconds. i am having difficulty adding a hyperlink to a new page for each image as it changes
here is my code thus far

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<script type = "text/javascript"  src = "timer.js" >

var arr = [];

arr[0]= new Image();
arr[0].src = "http://www.neonhusky.com/JShop/shopimages/products/thumbnails/SilX100-group.jpg";

arr[1]= new Image();
arr[1].src = "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/0/6393/528516-1ball2.jpg";

arr[2]= new Image();
arr[2].src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg";

arr[3]= new Image();
arr[3].src = "http://d1oqx90j8hion3.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/S/C/SC13_Training_Ball_2.jpg";


var i=0;

function slide(){
 document.getElementById("image1").src= arr[i].src;
 i++;
 if(i==arr.length){
  i=0;
 }
 setTimeout(function(){ slide(); },2000);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="slide('image1',arr);">
<div id="img" align = "center"><img id="image1" height="400px" width="400px" border="5" style="border-color:white;" /></div>

</body>

</html>
```

heres the questions i am asking
i have to associate with each of the four images a different link so that whenever the user clicks an image, its associated link is appeared in a new page.

side note i just added random images all copyright goes to the owners ill be using my own images when the code works

Comment: `slide()` doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should contain your img in a  tag and change its href attribute.
for example:

```
   <a id="link">
       <img .... />
   </a>
```

and in your function set it

```
   document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href','your link address');
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @G Z

See if this can help...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p975a/)

```
document.getElementById("image1").src= arr[i].src;
document.getElementById("link").setAttribute('href',links[i]);
```

I used a 2nd array to store the links.